# Calculated text column in SharePoint Online results in a ‘0’

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I would like either entry in the Status column to return a blank text value. Right now "Assigned" is resulting in a "0".

```
=IF(Status="Discontinued","",(IF(Status="Assigned","",[ABB ID])))
```

Comment: What is the data type of [ABB ID] column? Do you want to show blank value when status is either "Assigned" or "Discontinued"? can you please explain the conditions?

Comment: I'm sorry, [ABB ID] is a single line of text column which can contain no entry. Yes, I would like to show a blank value when Status (Choice column with the following choices - Discontinued, Assigned and Available) is either Assigned, Discontinued or no entry, but display the content of ABB ID when the value is Available. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone's assistance I was able to achieve the exact desired result using:

=IF(Status="Discontinued","",(IF(Status="Assigned","",(IF(ISBLANK([ABB ID]),"",[ABB ID])))))

I can't thank you enough and I appreciate your patience as I attempted to stumbled through the details! Thanks again!!!

Comment: Glad to know your problem is solved. You can mark your own reply as the Answer so that it will help others in this forum as well.

Comment: While using this formula, what happens if Status field is blank? what does this calculated formula returns in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try using below formula:

```
=IF(OR([Status]="Discontinued", [Status]="Assigned"), "", [ABB ID])
```

**Microsoft Official References**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14))
2. [OR function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/or-function-9a2a1cca-696f-4d19-a959-3943babd076f)

**Note**:

1. Return your calculated field as **Single line of text** (This setting is at the bottom of column settings page).

**Updates from comments**:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK([Status]), [Status]="Discontinued", [Status]="Assigned"), "", IF(ISBLANK([ABB ID]), "", [ABB ID]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Your formula works, but I should have better explained the situation. [ABB ID] is a single line of text column which can contain no entry. I would like to show a blank value when Status (Choice column with the following choices - Discontinued, Assigned and Available) is either Assigned, Discontinued or no entry, but display the content of ABB ID when the value is Available. Your formula displays a '0' when ABB ID is blank (which is exactly what my orginal formula does). Thank you!

Comment: @ArtBurnside Try solution given in my updated answer. It should work for you now.

Comment: If above doesn't work then try this: `=IF([Status]="Available", IF(ISBLANK([ABB ID]), "", [ABB ID]), "")`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have additional choices besides "*Discontinued*" or "*Assigned*" for the column "Status", or you have empty values for the column “ABB ID”.

You can use the double quote mark **""** anytime you want to return a blank text value in the calculated column, just add the additional conditions in the nested logic.

Here is an example:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([ABB ID]),"",
    IF(Status="Discontinued","",
        IF(Status="Assigned","",
            IF(Status="",[ABB ID])
        )
    )
)
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Since the formula in the other answer suits your need, I have modified it based on that one.

You can add another condition in the **OR** function so that it displays empty value when `[ABB ID]= ""`:

```
=IF(AND(OR([Status]="Discontinued", [Status]="Assigned", [Status]="Available"),ISBLANK([ABB ID])), "", [ABB ID])
```

Note: You did not mention what value should return when `[Status]="Available"`, so I put it in the condition same as the other two.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have better explained the situation. [ABB ID] is a single line of text column which can contain no entry. I would like to show a blank value when Status (Choice column with the following choices - Discontinued, Assigned and Available) is either Assigned, Discontinued or has no entry, but display the content of ABB ID when the value is Available. Your formula displays a blank entry for everything right now. I attempted to add "Available" (rather than "") in your last IF statement, but that made no changes. Thank you!

Comment: @ArtBurnside Please see the updated answer.